# Is necessary to ask user to add old password during change password

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently making a RESP API in wordpress for change password , so my concern is necessary **Old Password** during Change password .

Currently i am taking 3 parameters `uid,password` and `conf_passeor`

So should i need to ask for old password or not.

following is my code for change password.

```
if ( $_REQUEST['password'] != $_REQUEST['confirm_password'] ){
        $result = array('status'=>false,'message'=>'the passwords you entered do not match.');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo  json_encode($result);
        die();
    }

    if($_REQUEST['uid'] &&  $_REQUEST['password']){
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'] ;
        $data =wp_set_password( $password, $_REQUEST['uid'] );  
        $result = array('status'=>true,'message'=>'Password changed successfully.');        
    }else{
        $result = array('status'=>false,'message'=>'Something went wrong.');        
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo  json_encode($result);
        die();
```

If yes then how should i do this.

Comment: unless you have some other token which proves that the request is coming from that user (and that they are therefore authorised to make the change), then I'd say yes, absolutely you need to ask for the old password. Otherwise some other random person could just request to change this user's password without knowing any credentials, and then get access to the account.

Comment: The common way to do this is to send the user an email with a link containing a token that will validate their identity. Asking for the old password is often a bad option for authorisation here, because the most common reason to want to change your password is that you've forgotten your old one.

Comment: Actually iainn is correct, better to give the user a message (email is good) with some GUID which is both unique (not just to the user, but unique to that specific instance of email, and which may even expire over time) and very hard to guess, and they have to provide that (e.g. you can include it in a clickable URL as a querystring parameter which you can then read). Don't use the plain user ID or email as the token, as that's very easy to find out.

Comment: Duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30048/when-changing-a-password-using-a-webpage-must-the-old-password-be-entered-on-th